# moving range copy paste

Tags: vba, range, copy-paste

I have a data set of 24 hours of demand (rows) by 365 days (columns) and I need to convert this to one continuous vertical data series.  In other words create a macro that copies the second day's data and pastes it below the first and so on through the balance of the year.

I found an answer from Manji that is related (I think..) but I am not experienced enough to adapt this code to what I need.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here's what I'm looking at:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Dim oRange As range
Dim startColumn As String
Dim rangestart As Integer
Dim rangeEnd As Integer
Dim cellcount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

startColumn = "A"
rangestart = 1
rangeEnd = 24
cellcount = rangeEnd - rangestart + 1

For i = 1 To cellcount - 1
    Set oRange = ActiveSheet.range(startColumn & rangestart & ":" & startColumn & (rangeEnd - i))

    oRange.Copy
    oRange.Offset(i, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Set oRange = ActiveSheet.range(startColumn & (rangeEnd - i + 1) & ":" & startColumn & rangeEnd)

    oRange.Copy
    oRange.Offset((-1 * cellcount) + i, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your example worksheet, what it looks like now and show us how you would like it to look... explain what your code does and where does it throw an error or fail

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might help:

```
Sub DayHour()
Dim r As Long, c As Long, startRow As Long, hoursColumn As Long
Dim daysRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
daysRow = 1 ' this is the row where 'day 1', 'day 2' (or similar) is written
hoursColumn = 1 ' this is the column where 'hour 1', 'hour 2' (or similar) is written
r = Cells(Rows.Count, hoursColumn).End(xlUp).Row
c = Cells(daysRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = daysRow To r
    For j = hoursColumn To c
        With Sheets(2)
            .Cells(j, i) = Cells(i, j)
        End With
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

It writes the rearranged values in sheet 2 of the excel file. I think that's more or less, what you need. If you don't understand something or this isn't what you wanted, just leave a comment.

Little note: copy&paste in most cases isn't a good solution in VBA.

---

Edit: Something else came into my mind. **You don't have to do that in VBA.** Excel has a built-in function to do that.
Here is the explanation:

Select all of your data and press `Ctrl+C` (**important: not right click and copy**). Then you go to the area where you want your data to be placed. *(note: shouldn't be the same place from where you copied the data)*
Now do a right click on the cell and press on `Past Special..`. Activate `Transpose` and click `Ok`. The data should be in place now.

Comment: Thank you both for replying, sorry I've been offline.  My vba wasn't strong enough to figure out how to modify the code for my data set.  But I did figure out how to achieve the same thing using an offset function.  I just had to create an index for the dates so that it would count a new column for each new day and a new row for each new hour.  Once I did that the offset worked like a charm.  Thanks to all for the response.